# Issue with dynamic datatable in JSF

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces, rendering

I have an issue with dynamic datatable in java. I am creating multiple dynamic datatable in one simple toggle panel. Datatable is generated and getting displayed in the form(jsp page) properly. Data is also populating in the table. When i click on any commandlink in the table it opens the modal panel but doesnt display any data. when i refresh the page again then click on the commandlink the modal panel is showing the data.

So the issue is first time when datatable generates and i click on any link required data never comes up in the modal panel in the first button click. but if i go back and again come back to the same page then required data comes up in the modalpanel. Please suggest me the solution for this.

I have also noticed strange thing by comparing  view source of the page loads first time and second time, datatable name comes up without form name in first time like DATA_TABLE_NAME and second time datatable name comes up with form name e.g. formName:DATA_TABLE_NAME

I have been copying the logs of the datatable twice.
This is the first Time:

```
17:04:14,327 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,327 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,327 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,327 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,327 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,327 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,343 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,343 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,343 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,343 WARN  [HtmlLabelRenderer] Attribute 'for' of label component with id scopeItemsForm:taskMoreInfoNonScopePanelForm:j_id_jsp_151042
17:04:14,343 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:j_id165 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet.
17:04:14,343 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:j_id166 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet.
17:04:14,343 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id167 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,343 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id168 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id169 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id170 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id171 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id172 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id173 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id174 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id175 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id176 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id177 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id178 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
17:04:14,358 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id179 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet
```

and here is the second time

```
16:49:34,264 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id105 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,264 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id106 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,264 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id107 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,264 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id108 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,279 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id109 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,279 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id110 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,279 WARN  [HtmlImageRendererBase] ALT attribute is missing for : null
16:49:34,279 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,295 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id112 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,295 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id113 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,295 WARN  [HtmlImageRendererBase] ALT attribute is missing for : null
16:49:34,295 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id114 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
16:49:34,295 WARN  [UIComponentBase] WARNING: Component scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id115 just got an automatic id, because there was no id assigned yet. If this compo
```

First time HTML CODE comes like:

```
<table class="rich-table " id="ST_DATATBL_ID_0" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<colgroup span="12"></colgroup>
<thead class="rich-table-thead">
<tr class="rich-table-header  ">
<th class="rich-table-headercell " id="ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id107" width="20"></th>
<th class="rich-table-headercell " id="ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id108" width="2"></th>
<th class="rich-table-headercell " id="ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id109">ITEM #<img alt="" class="rich-spacer " height="1" id="ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id110" src="/pgsportal/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalimages/spacer.gif.jsf" width="10%" />
<a href="#" id="ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111" name="ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('scopeItemsForm',event,{'status':'notrequired','similarityGroupingId':'ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111','parameters':{'ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111':'ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111'} ,'containerId':'j_id0'} );return false;">
```

and second timme looks like:

```
    <table class="rich-table " id="scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <colgroup span="12"></colgroup>
    <thead class="rich-table-thead"><tr class="rich-table-header  ">
    <th class="rich-table-headercell " id="scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id107" width="20"></th><th class="rich-table-headercell " id="scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id108" width="2"></th>
    <th class="rich-table-headercell " id="scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id109">ITEM #
    <img alt="" class="rich-spacer " height="1" id="scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id110" src="/pgsportal/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalimages/spacer.gif.jsf" width="10%" />
    <a href="#" id="scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111" name="scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('scopeItemsForm',event,{'status':'notrequired','similarityGroupingId':'scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111','parameters':{'scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111':'scopeItemsForm:ST_DATATBL_ID_0:j_id111'} ,'containerId':'j_id0'} );return false;"><img src="../images/down_arrow.png" /></a>
```

Comment: You only posted the table header, where is the rest of the table HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have an ID issue.

When creating a label you can set the `for` attribute to point at an input with the same id:

```
<label for="someId">
    <input name="someInput" id="someId"/>
</label>
```

Since you didn't post any HTML it's hard to say exactly but you might have a label with empty `for`:

```
<label for="">
```

or the `for` is pointing at the wrong id:

```
<label for="someId">
    <input name="someInput" id="someOtherId"/>
</label>
```

Comment: <h:form id="scopeItemsForm"><a4j:outputPanel id="ScopePanel">
<rich:simpleTogglePanel switchType="client" label="SCOPE ITEM" binding="#{beanName.scopeSimpleTogglePanel}">
<f:facet name="openMarker">
<h:graphicImage value="../images/expand_icon.png" /></f:facet>
<f:facet name="closeMarker">
<h:graphicImage value="../images/collapse_icon.png" />
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:panelGroup layout="block" >
<h:outputText value="SCOPE ITEM"/>
</h:panelGroup>
</f:facet> </h:form> 
This is the jsp code using for the datatable.

Comment: please edit the question and put it there. also please put the actual generated HTML not the code.

Comment: @user1543894 Edit your question with your JSF code, also add the JSF and RichFaces version you're working with.